# How to get external player URL from the Vimeo API?

Tags: vimeo-api

I' trying to get the external player URL from the Vimeo API (URL like this: `https://player.vimeo.com/external/233547548.sd.mp4?s=d2dd296b3c068378ea3f544042c92ce2f803a62b&profile_id=222`). I have a business account and I'm trying to get those URL for my own videos. If I do a `GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/233547548` I can't find the external player URLs in the JSON data.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does your auth token have the `video_files` scope, and is it authenticated to the video owner?

Comment: It's authenticated to the video owner but didn't have the `video_files` scope. So this is probably my problem. I think it's not possible to modify an already created token, so, I need to create a new one with `video_files`, that's right?

Comment: It works, thanks! `video_files` scope was needed (have to create a new token for that). Is this information is somewhere in the docs?

Comment: It's touched upon here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#understanding-the-auth-process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by @Tommy Penner in the comments, you need to use an authorization token that have the `video_files` scope and be authenticated to the video owner.

The Vimeo API documentation is a bit light on the subject but the relevant info is here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#understanding-the-auth-process

Thanks Tommy